# Have custom options and databound items in html select

Tags: c#, html, .net, vb.net, bootstrap-4

I am currently trying to have a select contain a default value in the options section, while also databinding it using a sqldatasource. I know that asp:Dropdowns have the appenddatabounditems attribute, but was curious if select controls also have something similar. Or if there is any way to do this at all.

```
<select id="ddlRFC" runat="server" datasourceid="dsRFC" DataTextField="ControlDescription" DataValueField="ControlValue" class="form-control">
      <option selected>Choose...</option>                                   
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. Looking at [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/HtmlControls/HtmlSelect.cs,627), any existing items are always cleared when the `HtmlSelect` control is data-bound:

```
/* Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. */

// create items using the datasource
if (dataSource != null) {
    ...
    Items.Clear();
```